# What is the relation of backup image size and actual database size in Netezza

Tags: backup, netezza

May I know what would be roughly ideal ratio between full backup image size and actual database size in netezza.
Few things I know is, 
it depends on actual data in the tables, internal compression, number of tables in the db etc.

Answer (score 1):

Data stored "at rest" in Netezza are compressed, as they are also in backups.  However, the compression algorithms & methods employed are different.  That being said, one can typically expect that the size and compression ratio of the two to be roughly the same.

Comment: Thanks Scott for the info. 
I found that in  nz_backup script there is an option -sizedata, which calculate the size taken by backup image if we do actual backup.for any database.